# Is there a way to multiply archive loop results sequentially?

Tags: archives, blog, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make my own version [of this](http://demo.codestag.com/ink/) I've implemented bootstrap grid in my attempt. I'm very close, but the `<div class="row">` being looped is causing problems.

I want to just be able to build my html structure with bootstrap and not rely soley on the `if` statements that control how many archives are spit out.

Is there a way to add as many `<?php the_post_thumbnail('category-thumbnail'); ?>` (for example) as I want so it sequentially spits out the blogs in order?

```
<?php
$count = 0;
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

if ( $count < 1 ) { ?>
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <a class="thumb" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('category-thumbnail'); ?></a>
        <div class="blog-details-wrapper clear">
            <h2 class="title">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            </h2>
            <span class="date"><?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?> <?php the_time('g:i a'); ?></span>
            <span class="author"><?php _e( 'Published by', 'html5blank' ); ?> <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></span>
            <span class="comments"><?php if (comments_open( get_the_ID() ) ) comments_popup_link( __( 'Leave your thoughts', 'html5blank' ), __( '1 Comment', 'html5blank' ), __( '% Comments', 'html5blank' )); ?></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php } elseif ( $count <= 2 ) { ?>
  <div class="row" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <a class="thumb" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('category-thumbnail'); ?></a>
        <div class="blog-details-wrapper clear">
            <h2 class="title">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            </h2>
            <span class="date"><?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?> <?php the_time('g:i a'); ?></span>
            <span class="author"><?php _e( 'Published by', 'html5blank' ); ?> <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></span>
            <span class="comments"><?php if (comments_open( get_the_ID() ) ) comments_popup_link( __( 'Leave your thoughts', 'html5blank' ), __( '1 Comment', 'html5blank' ), __( '% Comments', 'html5blank' )); ?></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <a class="thumb" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('category-thumbnail'); ?></a>
        <div class="blog-details-wrapper clear">
            <h2 class="title">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            </h2>
            <span class="date"><?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?> <?php the_time('g:i a'); ?></span>
            <span class="author"><?php _e( 'Published by', 'html5blank' ); ?> <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></span>
            <span class="comments"><?php if (comments_open( get_the_ID() ) ) comments_popup_link( __( 'Leave your thoughts', 'html5blank' ), __( '1 Comment', 'html5blank' ), __( '% Comments', 'html5blank' )); ?></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<?php } $count++;
endwhile;

?>
```

So in the above code: I would be able to call a blog/blogs in each row, but it would the next blog in sequential order. So in this case: one that spans the whole browser and then 2 50% width ones right next to eachother, then repeat structure for more blogs.

Is this possible? Is there a way to make a variable or something that allows you to a call archives repeatedly while sequentially spitting out the archives and not repeating the same ones?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$counter = 1; 

if(have_posts()) :  while(have_posts()) :  the_post(); 
?>
<?php
if($counter == 1) :
?>
            <div class="row clear" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
                <div class="col-md-12 border-12">
                    <a class="thumb" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('category-thumbnail'); ?></a>
                    <div class="blog-details-wrapper clear">
                    <h2 class="title">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                    </h2>
                        <span class="date"><?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?> <?php the_time('g:i a'); ?></span>
                        <span class="author"><?php _e( 'Published by', 'html5blank' ); ?> <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></span>
                        <span class="comments"><?php if (comments_open( get_the_ID() ) ) comments_popup_link( __( 'Leave your thoughts', 'html5blank' ), __( '1 Comment', 'html5blank' ), __( '% Comments', 'html5blank' )); ?></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

<?php

elseif($counter == 2) :
?>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 border">
                    <a class="thumb-6" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('category-thumbnail'); ?></a>
                    <div class="blog-details-wrapper clear">
                    <h2 class="">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                    </h2>
                        <span class="date"><?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?> <?php the_time('g:i a'); ?></span>
                        <span class="author"><?php _e( 'Published by', 'html5blank' ); ?> <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></span>
                        <span class="comments"><?php if (comments_open( get_the_ID() ) ) comments_popup_link( __( 'Leave your thoughts', 'html5blank' ), __( '1 Comment', 'html5blank' ), __( '% Comments', 'html5blank' )); ?></span>
                    </div>
                </div>

<?php
elseif($counter >= 2) : ?>

                <div class="col-md-6 border">
                    <a class="thumb-6" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('category-thumbnail'); ?></a>
                    <div class="blog-details-wrapper clear">
                    <h2 class="">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                    </h2>
                        <span class="date"><?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?> <?php the_time('g:i a'); ?></span>
                        <span class="author"><?php _e( 'Published by', 'html5blank' ); ?> <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></span>
                        <span class="comments"><?php if (comments_open( get_the_ID() ) ) comments_popup_link( __( 'Leave your thoughts', 'html5blank' ), __( '1 Comment', 'html5blank' ), __( '% Comments', 'html5blank' )); ?></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>  

<?php 
$counter = 0;
endif;
?>
<?php
$counter++;
endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The common loop implementation loops for *every* post. It is so pervasive that it's not obvious it being entirely optional.

The "every" part comes from `while ( have_posts() )`, the advancing from `the_post()`. The former is completely technically optional.

You can advance by one post simply calling `the_post()` and surrounding it by *any other logic* you deem necessary. Of course if your requirements are more complex then it would also take more complex logic than simple `while()`.

I had blogged about this before [Asymmetrical WordPress loops](http://www.rarst.net/wordpress/asymmetrical-loops/).

Comment: I think that this is the longest way to say "yes, everything is possible" I saw so far :)

Comment: That would be a succinct, but very very downvoted answer. :)

Comment: @Rarst I appreciate the effort, but strongly agree with the two other comments. I actually read your Asymmetrical Loop article and I'm still a little lost, because it's not obvious to me how to use normal PHP and put the results in a variable to use at my discretion. It all makes sense but it's a little vague. A more applicable to my question explanation would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: The issue is this technique is well into "normal PHP" territory. This is precisely the point when just moving WP stuff around ends and you _need_ to be able to plan and write actual PHP code. :) It's middle of the night here, will see if I can get to it tomorrow.

Comment: @Rarst I am fully aware this requires "normal PHP". When you get a chance, go back and read my question and you can see that I am already using it :) I figured it out. I'll answer my own question. However, feel free to post your solution, I would be interested to see it.

Comment: @RLM that would work just fine, seem like I might have had more complicated take in mind :)